# How to reduce the size of bootable img file?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, live-usb, raspberrypi

have downloaded a bootable img file(ubuntu for raspiberry).BUT it's size(8.1GB) is a little larger than my sdcard(7.8GB)! I noticed that the img file have many free space in it.So how can I remove these free space and reduce the img size to make it smaller?

Comment: When I look at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi it says the compressed image size is 214MB. 8.1GB uncompressed seems excessive...

Comment: The img I downloaded is ubuntu mate (https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say you need to purchase a new SD card. At ([Ubuntu Mate - Raspberry Pi](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/)) they say:

> We have done what we can to optimise the build for the Raspberry Pi 2
>   and Raspberry Pi 3, you can comfortably use applications such as
>   LibreOffice, which in fact is a joy to use :-) But the microSDHC I/O
>   throughput is a bottleneck so **we *highly* recommend that you use a
>   Class 6 or Class 10 microSDHC** card. **Ubuntu MATE 16.04 also has
>   fully working Bluetooth and Wifi on the Raspberry Pi 3**
>
> You’ll need a microSD card which is **8GB** or greater to fit the
>   image. The file system can be resized to occupy the unallocated space
>   of the microSD card, **on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 this can be done via
>   Ubuntu MATE Welcome.**

In effect you don't have an installation .ISO on your hands you have an image of the fully installed operating system.

The good news is you can get a **32 GB Class 10 Card* for $13.49 from: ([ebay.com - SanDisk Ultra Class 10 32GB microSD](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SanDisk-Ultra-Class-10-32GB-microSD-micro-SDHC-SD-UHS-I-U1-TF-Flash-Memory-Card-/191928701424)). I would highly recommend this move as it will leave you 24 GB for applications and data. Plus extra working storage space for upgrading new kernels, new Ubuntu Mate distributions, etc.